# Sorting set based on class member parameter during insertion with Boost

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, insert, set

I've just started learning the basics of Boost and I'm currently dealing with the following exercise:

> Create a program with multiple objects of a type animal with the member variables name, legs and has_tail. Store the objects in a container from Boost.PointerContainer. Sort the container in ascending order based on legs and write all elements to standard output.

The issue stems from the fact that I cannot sort the container AFTER the insertion has been done, and I should probably try to use only the PointerContainer library.

The following is the code I've wrote based on one of the examples provided by the tutorial

```
class Animal{
    private:
        std::string name;
        int legs;
        bool hasTail;
    public:
        Animal() = delete;
        Animal(char* aName, int nLegs = 0, bool sTail = false) : name(aName), legs(nLegs), hasTail(sTail) {};
        inline int getLegs(){ return legs; };
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Animal& animal);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Animal& animal)
{
  os << "Name: " << animal.name << " || Legs: " << animal.legs << " || Has a tail? " << animal.hasTail << std::endl;
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  Animal cat("Cat", 4, true), spider("Common Spider", 8, false), slug("Slug");
  std::set<std::unique_ptr<Animal>, boost::indirect_fun<std::less<int>>> v;
  v.insert(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(&cat));
  v.insert(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(&spider));
  v.insert(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(&slug));

  //print result

}
```

Of course I know the reason why this doesn't build is because I'm trying to use indirect_fun with an int parameter but I'm passing an object of type Animal to the set, it's just to give you the idea of what tools I'm "allowed" to use for the exercise and what the general idea I had would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to 'tell' `std::less` how to compare your `Animal` objects:

```cpp
bool operator<(const Animal& a, const Animal& b) { return a.getLegs() < b.getLegs(); }
```

(and also make `getLegs()` `const` for this to work).
Updated example:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_set.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/indirect_fun.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


class Animal{
    private:
        std::string name;
        int legs;
        bool hasTail;
    public:
        Animal() = delete;
        Animal(std::string aName, int nLegs = 0, bool sTail = false) : name(aName), legs(nLegs), hasTail(sTail) {};
        inline int getLegs() const{ return legs; };
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Animal& animal);
};

bool operator<(const Animal& a, const Animal& b) { return a.getLegs() < b.getLegs(); }

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Animal& animal)
{
  os << "Name: " << animal.name << " || Legs: " << animal.legs << " || Has a tail? " << animal.hasTail << std::endl;
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  std::set<std::unique_ptr<Animal>, boost::indirect_fun<std::less<Animal>>> v;
  v.insert(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Animal("Cat", 4, true)));
  v.insert(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Animal("Common Spider", 8, false)));
  v.insert(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Animal("Slug")));

  for(const auto& animal: v)
  {
    std::cout << *animal << std::endl;   
  }
}
```

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
Name: Slug || Legs: 0 || Has a tail? 0

Name: Cat || Legs: 4 || Has a tail? 1

Name: Common Spider || Legs: 8 || Has a tail? 0
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d8f635dc357404f